# Building QuantLib python bindings on windows 7: 'unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin''

Tags: python, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I'm trying to build the QuantLib Python bindings. I managed to build QuantLib using [these](http://www.wilmott.com/messagepost.cfm?postaction=reply&catid=10&threadid=80885&messid=529629&STARTPAGE=1&parentid=529629) instructions (I found the libboost_serialization files [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.46.1/)). When I try python setup.py build, I get the following error

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'QuantLib._QuantLib' extension
C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC -c QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\quantlib\quantlib_wrap.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've heard that the mno-cygwin option is no longer supported and I've seen it removed from numpy distutils, but as far as I can tell this is only using python distutils. Any hints on what I should look at?

- windows 7
- python 2.6
- numpy 1.5.1
- QuantLib 1.46.1

Comment: The instructions you linked mention using Visual C++ Express, yet your output tells that distutils tries to use gcc.  What are you actually using?

Comment: I thought VC express was for compiling QuantLib not for the QuantLib bindings. I already successfully built QuantLib itself. Do you interpret the instructions differently?

Comment: Well, I don't see mingw or gcc mentioned anywhere in the instructions, and I do build the bindings with VC++9.  Distutils works rather well with it, since Python itself is built with the VC++ compiler on Windows.  Also, I don't know that a library compiled with VC++ and bindings compiled with gcc are binary compatible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that Python 2.6 distutils hasn't caught up with MinGW ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-op)). I now get another error, but that's for another question.

Answer (score 3):

I've done a tutorial that builds Quantlib Python bindings on Windows (Vista and XP). This probably will work with Windows 7 as well and you don't need Visual Studio. [here](http://tumblr.tvieira.com/post/8001088165/quantlib-and-python)

Comment: @sanjay-t-sharma I'm sorry for that. I use Zone Edit for my DNS management (free), and they have been silly leaving DNS servers sometimes more than 48 hours down.