# Using pip to install fabric, Cygwin giving strange errors

Tags: python, cygwin, fabric

I am trying to install fabric through cygwin. I have worked through numerous problems to get to this point, but now I am met with an error which is seemingly not documented in this capacity anywhere.. Any ideas?

```
 $ pip install fabric
```

I am getting a result of lots of 'copying' etc etc followed by the followinf three lines.

```
    cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Which version of gcc (do gcc --version)? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o.

Comment: 4.6.1 apparently.. is that of any further aid?

Comment: The page you linked does not actually have any specified fix - could anyone advise on this? Thanks

Comment: The fix on that page states removing that flag or installing an older version.