# where is python getting this build command from?

Tags: python, cygwin, installation, volatility

**background**

I am installing volatility from this [walkthrough](http://code.google.com/p/volatility/wiki/FullInstallation). I am doing this on a windows 7 64 bit install and i have python 2.7 installed. I had cygwin installed months ago and removed it probably 6+ months ago. I have cleared all references to it i can find and all files associated with it. Where is python getting the "-mno-cygwin" from? Any help or links would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Current path variable**

```
C:\Python27\;
C:\Python27\Scripts;
C:\MinGW\bin;
C:\Perl64\site\bin;
C:\Perl64\bin;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
%TTPRO_APPDIR%;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
```

**error**

```
C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\pycrypto-2.6.tar\dist\pycrypto-2.6\pycrypto-2.6>pyth
on setup.py build -c mingw32
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.

building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -Wall -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -
Isrc/ -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src/winrand.c -o build\temp.win-
amd64-2.7\Release\src\winrand.o
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: well you are attempting to install pycrypto from what I see here. And for some reason GMP or MPIR library is not found and it is attempting to automatically correct this

Comment: @gabeDel right. so where is it looking for "-mno-cygwin"? I cant figure it out and it is breaking my build attempts it looks like.

Comment: apparently that is in the setup.py file that you are running and it is noticing that GMP or MPIR are not there so either it is trying to get one of the or blindly trying to continue and execute that command which I'm guessing is in the original setup.py so check pycrypto's setup.py file for that long string... but do you have gcc installed at C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe ?

Comment: @gabeDel yes i do have gcc.exe installed in that directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645004/python-mno-cygwin) suggests that the -mno-cygwin option can be found in c:\Python27\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py and that it is a deprecated option that can be removed.