# How to install older mingw versions to install python package (leven)

Tags: python, c++, mingw

Long version: I have a python package that is written in C++ (called leven), to install it I need to build the leven package by compiling it in c++. For this I tried using Visual C++ and Mingw. The error code in Visual c++ was generic, so I decided to use mingw instead (which I already had installed since I used to use Codeblocks).

The problem is that when trying to build I get the following error message: "mno-cygwin unrecognized", after some research, it appears that such command has been deprecated (people said finally!). however, I need it to finish installing my package. So my question is, how can I install a previous version of mingw? should I uninstall codeblocks and the current mingw version?

tldr, Need to install previous version of mingw cpp compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove -mno-cygwin option from Makefile and you are in

Comment: What's the Makefile? and where do I find it?

Comment: It's just a text file with build options in the source code tree of your library. Just find text `-mno-cygwin` and erase all occurences

Comment: I did that. I went through every file in the package I am trying to install, and I couldn't find any instance of -mno-cygwin. This is the package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/leven/

Comment: I forgot you are using python package. See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645004/python-mno-cygwin and edit file in python installation as described in answer

Comment: Great that helped. I was able to fix that issue. Although now I'm getting a different error.. "g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--output-lib'