# Errors when installing cython on windows

Tags: python, windows-7, cygwin, mingw, cython

I was trying to install `cython` on `windows 7` using `python setup.py install`. But it encountered an error:

```
C:\Cython-0.16>C:\Python27\python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Pytho
n27\PC -c Cython\Plex\Scanners.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\cython\plex\sca
nners.o
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am using `Python 2.7`, I have `MinGW` and `Cygwin` installed on the system. I tried to google it. But there isn't a similar problem.

I used `mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe` to install the `MinGW` version 4.5.

Comment: You probably need some newer version of MinGW. You didn't specify what gcc version you have and that is crucial to your problem.

Comment: +Czarek Tomczak It's version 4.5

Answer (score 0):

`-mno-cygwin` in `Python\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py` causes this problem: see [Compiling with cython and mingw produces gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o) or http://korbinin.blogspot.com/2013/03/cython-mno-cygwin-problems.html. My Python distribution (Anaconda)'s `cygwinccompiler.py` does not have that though. Anyway, after removing all `-mno-cygwin` in the definition of the `Mingw32CCompiler` class you should be able to compile.