# Can't compile Cython code - unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

Tags: python, numpy, cygwin, cython

I am trying to compile some Python / Numpy code into Cython for speedup. I can compile just fine on my desktop - I copied my .pyx Cython file to my laptop to run it and after attempting to compile, I get the following error:

```
C:\Python27\MATH7450>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning heat.pyx to heat.c
building 'heat' extension
C:\strawberry\c\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\lib\site-pa
ckages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c heat.c -o bu
ild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\heat.o
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit. I see it is using strawberry perl. I have the 32 bit version of strawberry perl installed. Again, it works just fine on my desktop, but getting this strange error when porting to laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Windows installation instructions of Cython](http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows), the recommended compiler is free Visual C++ 2008 Express, which can be installed from the offline installation [Visual Studio 2008 Express iso](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20682).

Alternatively [Cython can use the MinGW and its gcc](http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows), although this is a [reportedly more difficult route](http://coindoorinterlock.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/installing-working-cython-on-windows.html).

From the output included in your question, Cython is trying to use the MinGW installation included with the *Strawberry Perl* distribution.

My recommendation is to install *Visual C++ 2008 Express*, which from my experience works best for compiling Cython or other Python C extension modules.

Answer (score 1):

`-mno-cygwin` in `Python\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py` causes this problem: see [Compiling with cython and mingw produces gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o) or http://korbinin.blogspot.com/2013/03/cython-mno-cygwin-problems.html. My Python distribution (Anaconda)'s `cygwinccompiler.py` does not have that though. Anyway, after removing all `-mno-cygwin` in the definition of the `Mingw32CCompiler` class you should be able to compile.