# Compiling pygraphviz: Unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

Tags: python, mingw32, pygraphviz

On Windows 7, when trying to compile pygraphviz, I run

```
    python setup.py build -c mingw32
```

I get

> C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Graphv
>   iz 2.28\include\graphviz" -Ic:\Python27\include -Ic:\Python27\PC -c pygraphviz/g
>   raphviz_wrap.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.o
>   cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
>   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Where is that '-mno-cygwin' coming from?  Greping through the pygraphviz-1.1 directory shows no occurences of "no-cygwin".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6035864/1516291

In short, you may need to modify `distutils\cygwinccompiler.py` in your python installation dir to remove traces of `-mno-cygwin`.

Comment: It's important to note that this option exists in the setup.py file of a few packages, such that 'pip install cx_Oracle,' for example, will fail with the same message.  The source file needs to be downloaded so that setup.py can be edited.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem which has been fixed by replacing instances of the string "-mno-cygwin" with "" in the `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py`

i.e.
Original code:

```
    self.set_executables(compiler='gcc -mno-cygwin -O -Wall',
                         compiler_so='gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall',
                         compiler_cxx='g++ -mno-cygwin -O -Wall',
                         linker_exe='gcc -mno-cygwin',
                         linker_so='%s -mno-cygwin %s %s'
                                    % (self.linker_dll, shared_option,
                                       entry_point))
```

Updated code:

```
    self.set_executables(compiler='gcc "" -O -Wall',
                         compiler_so='gcc "" -mdll -O -Wall',
                         compiler_cxx='g++ "" -O -Wall',
                         linker_exe='gcc ""',
                         linker_so='%s "" %s %s'
                                    % (self.linker_dll, shared_option,
                                       entry_point))
```

What version GCC compiler do you use? You will not get this issue if you use GCC 3.4.4 otherwise you need to replace "-mno-cygwin" string with empty quotes as mentioned above especially for GCC 4.3.7.