# vectorization of looping on an array from cython

Tags: gcc, cython, auto-vectorization

Consider the following example of doing an inplace-add on a Cython memoryview:

```
#cython: boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, nonecheck=False, cdivision=True
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.stdio cimport printf
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np


cdef extern from "time.h":
    int clock()


cdef void inplace_add(double[::1] a, double[::1] b):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        a[i] += b[i]


cdef void inplace_addlocal(double[::1] a, double[::1] b):
    cdef int i, n = a.shape[0]
    for i in range(n):
        a[i] += b[i]


def main(int N):
    cdef:
        int rep = 1000000, i
        double* pa = <double*>malloc(N * sizeof(double))
        double* pb = <double*>malloc(N * sizeof(double))
        double[::1] a = <double[:N]>pa
        double[::1] b = <double[:N]>pb
        int start
    start = clock()
    for i in range(N):
        a[i] = b[i] = 1. / (1 + i)
    for i in range(rep):
        inplace_add(a, b)
    printf("loop %i\n", clock() - start)
    print(np.asarray(a)[:4])
    start = clock()
    for i in range(N):
        a[i] = b[i] = 1. / (1 + i)
    for i in range(rep):
        inplace_addlocal(a, b)
    printf("loop_local %i\n", clock() - start)
    print(np.asarray(a)[:4])
```

With these Cython directives, the seemingly equivalent `inplace_add` and `inplace_addlocal` both compile to tight C loops.  But for `N=128` (the approximate size I'm expecting) `inplace_addlocal` is twice(!) faster than `inplace_add`, after compilation with `gcc -Ofast` (and directly writing a C function taking a (int, double*, double*) is more or less as fast as `addlocal`, with or without `#openmp simd`).  Passing `-fopt-info` to `gcc` shows that `inplace_addlocal` gets vectorized, but not `inplace_add`.

Is this an issue with the C code that Cython generates (i.e., gcc truly cannot infer whatever guarantees it needs to vectorize the code), or with gcc (i.e., some optimization is missing), or something else?

Thanks.

(cross-posted to cython-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference for the generated C code is that in `inplace_addlocal` the end variable for the loop is an `int`, while in `inplace_add` it's a `Py_ssize_t`.

Since your loop counter is an `int`, in the `inplace_add` version, there would be an aditional overhead due to casting between the two types when the comparison is performed.

**inplace_add** (relevant section)

```
Py_ssize_t __pyx_t_1;
int __pyx_t_2;
int __pyx_t_3;
int __pyx_t_4;

__pyx_t_1 = (__pyx_v_a.shape[0]);
for (__pyx_t_2 = 0; __pyx_t_2 < __pyx_t_1; __pyx_t_2+=1) {
  __pyx_v_i = __pyx_t_2;
```

**inplace_addlocal** (relevant section)

```
int __pyx_t_1;
int __pyx_t_2;
int __pyx_t_3;
int __pyx_t_4;

__pyx_v_n = (__pyx_v_a.shape[0]);
__pyx_t_1 = __pyx_v_n;
for (__pyx_t_2 = 0; __pyx_t_2 < __pyx_t_1; __pyx_t_2+=1) {
  __pyx_v_i = __pyx_t_2;
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20987501/1791279) mentions that is it preferable to use `Py_ssize_t` for indices (and it must be assumed by default in Cython), which would solve this problem.

Comment: Good catch.  Either declaring `i` as `size_t` or casting `a.shape[0]` to `int` in the call to range allows vectorization.