# Installing Ephem package in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, pyephem

I would like to install the *ephem* package in my Python 3.3.0 version under Windows XP.

I tried first the *pip install ephem* route from the system command prompt. The process aborted with the error message of *Unable to find vcvarsall.bat*.

I read prior advice on the net for such a difficulty. Following it I installed *mingw32* in my computer, added *C:\MinGW\bin* to the *PATH* variable and provided *Lib / distutils* with a new file called *distutils.cfg* and the content:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

On running now any of the install commands (*pip*, *easy_install* and *setup.py* all work the same) the following error results:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Ilibastro-3.7.5 -IC:\Python33\
include -IC:\Python33\include -c extensions/_libastro.c -o build\temp.win32-3.3\
Release\extensions\_libastro.o

cc1.exe: error: unrecognised command line option '-mno-cygwin'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have tried to understand and solve the problem, but have been unsuccesful. I have not been able even to find the place in the code where such values are established.

¿Could somebody provide any help? ¿Would *ephem* be one of the cases alluded by *Installing Python modules* in the *3.3.0 Documentation* with "Not all extensions can be built with MinGW or Cygwin, but many can."?

Thanks in advance

Paco

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extremely useful page of Windows binaries of python packages: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

It includes binaries for [pyephem](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyephem).

Comment: You are right. I have used it in other instances and it is excellent and extremely useful.