# installing ephem with conda on python 3.6

Tags: python, anaconda, pyephem

I'm using Python 3.6 on Anaconda, and I need to use the ephem package. I used the command :

```
conda install -c anaconda ephem
```

It returns an error, saying that epecifications were found in conflict : ephem requires Python 2.6.

Is there a way I can use ephem on Python 3.6 with Anaconda?

Comment: Did you try `pip install ephem` ?

Comment: No. I heard that mixing pip and conda could lead to bad results.

Comment: Maybe.  (1) I have been doing it for a couple of years without any problems (2) If you are really set on installing using conda, then you can make your own  [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/)

Comment: I tried with pip, and it returned an error too. Apparently it requires Visual C++ compilation, which is not available on my corporate laptop.

Comment: I followed this [post][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024443/installing-ephem-package-in-python-3?rq=1], it worked well

Answer (score 2):

I used the following to successfully install ephem for Python 3.6 (Running Spyder with Python 3.6):

```
conda install -c astropy pyephem
```

[I found the info at this link from Anaconda.](https://anaconda.org/astropy/pyephem)