# Windows - pip install with mingw - Fails - cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

Tags: python-2.7, mingw, pip

I am using Python27

My PATH contains

```
C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2
C:\MinGW\bin
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
C:\Python27\
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

My PYTHONPATH contains

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python\Lib\site-packages
```

When I try to install certain packages I keep getting errors with gcc

```
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
```

seems like it is the culprit, but I've been unable to find information on how to fix this.

Some Examples of Errors:

```
pip install ctypes 
....
building '_ctypes' extension

    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Isource/libffi_msvc -IC:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\boost_1_53_0 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c source/_ctypes.c -o
    build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\source\_ctypes.o

    cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

another with the same issue

```
pip install bzr
....
building 'bzrlib._annotator_pyx' extension

C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -DWIN32 -IC:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\boost_1_53_0 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c bzrlib/_annotator_pyx.c -o build\
temp.win32-2.7\Release\bzrlib\_annotator_pyx.o

cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'



  Cannot build extension "bzrlib._annotator_pyx".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-mno-cygwin` in `Python\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py` causes this problem: see [Compiling with cython and mingw produces gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o) or http://korbinin.blogspot.com/2013/03/cython-mno-cygwin-problems.html.

My Python distribution (Anaconda)'s `cygwinccompiler.py` does not have that though. Anyway, after removing all `-mno-cygwin` in the definition of the `Mingw32CCompiler` class you should be able to compile.