# python installation "cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'"

Tags: python-2.7, mingw32, rrdtool

Hi guys i'm trying to install rrdtool (for PYTHON 2.7) on my windows 7 system , i install it using this command line.

```
python setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32
```

it gives me the following output:

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
running build_configure
building 'rrdtoolmodule' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Irrdtool-1.4.7/src -IC:\Python2
7\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c rrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdtoolmodule.c -o b
uild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7\bindings\python\rrdtoolmodule.o
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

i have tried many solutions to solve this, but had no success.i'm using mingw version 4.6.2

can anyone pls help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6035864/1516291

you need to edit distutils\cygwinccompiler.py in your Python directory to remove all instances of -mno-cygwin

good luck