# Getting Cython to work in Windows 7 with Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, cython

I'm a newbie trying to learn Cython. My operating system is Windows 7 and I'm using Eclipse PyDev as my IDE for Python development.

I have tried to install and test Cython according to [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html) guide:

[image]

Here is the content of my environment variable `PATH`:

```
C:\texlive\2012\bin\win32;C:\Users\jjepoh\Jonne's_Programs\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\jjepoh\Jonne's_Programs\SSH client;C:\Users\jjepoh\Jonne's_Programs\Python\Scripts;
```

MinGW is installed under Codeblocks:

[image]

I have installed Cython 0.20.1 using the Windows binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython):

[image]

I have Python 2.7.5 installed:

[image]

Here you can see Cython installed under Python:

[image]

My `hello.pyx, test_cython.py` and `setup.py` according to the guide:

[image]

It seems I can compile the c-file, but I am doing something wrong I think..here is the end result:

[image]

Do you guys have any idea, what am I missing here? Why can't I import the `hello.pyx` module?

Thank you for any assistance. Sorry for the large amount of pictures, I thought it would help to give as much details as possible. I will give more details when asked =)

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat Your c- file isn't compiling properly. That strikes me as odd though since I usually expect this error with 64 bit installations of Python. The second answer to the other question will probably fix it for you.

Comment: @IanH I got it working! =) This one http://stackoverflow.com/a/10501736/1565754 and this one did it! http://stackoverflow.com/a/6035864/1565754

Comment: Great! I'm glad it's working for you now. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved with the hints provided by user @IanH =)

Here are the links to the solution:

[error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/10501736#10501736)

[Compiling with cython and mingw produces gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o/6035864#6035864)

Here you can see the result =)

[image]