# Compiling Yap on windows 8

Tags: c++, prolog, cygwin, yap, aleph-ilp

I am trying to compile yap on my PC since it seems YAP default installers don't come with the Depth limit flag enabled. I need this to work on an ILP project on Aleph.

The thing is, that I am forced to use a PC with windows 8 without enough memory for a Linux Virtual machine. 
I got cygwin to attempt to install it, but once I get to the 'make' stage of the installation ( http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/Yap4.3/yap.html#SEC2 ) I get this following error

```
$ make
Makefile:714: warning: overriding recipe for target 'yap.dll'
Makefile:545: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'yap.dll'
gcc  -mno-cygwin -c -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -g -O2 -DCUT_C=1  -DCOROUTINING=1 -DRATIONAL_TREES=1 -DDEPTH_LIMIT=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_YAP_NOT_INSTALLED_=1 -I. -I../H -I../OPTYap -I../BEAM -I../MYDDAS ../C/agc.c -o agc.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-cygwin’
Makefile:488: recipe for target 'agc.o' failed
make: *** [agc.o] Error 1
```

I assume it's due to the latest YAP being outdated right now, does anyone know what to do to work around this?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6035864/3604121). It could be that you have a new gcc version that hasn't that option anymore. Maybe try just to remove the option from the makefile.

Comment: Without it I get a message with the following  line at the end Makefile:488: "recipe for target 'agc.o' failed" Are you sure I shouldn't replace it with something else?

Comment: Sorry, I just stumbled across the other answer and thought that might help. I don't know the details of YAP'c build process.

Answer (score 2):

It seems long time has passed since the question is asked. But I would like to answer since the problem is still relevant (I had this problem lately).

Asking at YAP-users mailing list, I was  able to solve this problem. You can check the details [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/yap/mailman/message/34940401/).

In short, using MSYS2 or MinGW-w64 (with toolchain installed) and making few changes in the source code makes it possible.

Changes are:

- Adding `#include <stdio.h>` in *blob.c* file.
- Refactoring `H` with `HEAD` (or some other name) in whole project. Which was defined in *Regs.h*, *line 590*.