# Python 3.4: compile cython module for 64-bit windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cython, distutils, mingw-w64

I have a .pyx module that I've been trying to compile for use with 64-bit python 3.4 on Windows through various means but with no success.

After a lot of trial and error, it does compile with

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32
```

but of course, that won't work with 64-bit python.

With msvc as the compiler, the error is

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: ['path']
```

- Windows 7
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 installed
- There appears to be some Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 stuff in C:\Program Files (x86) (including vcvarsall.bat)

Solutions that don't revolve around distutils are also welcome.

--- EDIT: Additional information

I have now modified distutils to recognize mingw-w64 as per http://bugs.python.org/issue11723. I then made libpython34.a using gendef and dlltool, but get an error

```
c:\Python34\libs/libpython34.a: file not recongnized: File truncated
```

when running

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw64
```

Comment: Why not install the 64-bit mingw toolchain?

Comment: Any one in particular you would recommend? As far as I've seen there are a few... I have mingw-w64 installed, but distutils doesn't offer it as an option, so I suppose there's more to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, at long last I managed to make it work.

The fantastic resources by Christoph Gohlke (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) are key.

1. Install your desired Python version in the conventional way
2. Install any extensions you need from Gohlke's site
3. Install MinGW-w64 from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download
4. Patch distutils as per http://bugs.python.org/issue11723
5. Install the appropriate version of libpython from Gohlke's site
6. Bob's yer uncle

(Trying all sorts of wild suggestions for this task, I have gone through many more steps but as far as I can tell, these are the only ones that actually made a difference in the end)

Comment: to also apply it to the newest version of MinGW-w64 you have to slightly change the patch and remove all -mno-cygwin parameters from cygwinccompiler.py see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o/6035864#6035864