# Install Cython in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, 64-bit, cython, mingw-w64, mingw32

I know this question is asked a lot, but I can't figure it out:
I have trouble to install Cython library on my Windows 10 machine:

I have:

- OS : Win 10, 64 bit
- Python --version : 3.7.0b1
- [Mingw 64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)

I do:

- Install Mingw 64
- Add the path to `C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin`
- I created `distutils.cfg` file inside `PYTHON_PATH\Lib\distutils`

add

```
 [build]
 compiler = mingw32
```

inside

- Manually applying this [patch](https://bugs.python.org/file40608/patch.diff)
- Manually downloading the file [`vcruntime140.dll`](https://www.dll-files.com/vcruntime140.dll.html)(build : 14.0.23918.0) and putting it in `PYTHON_PATH\libs`
- Downloaded the [Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython) code
- Run the command python setup.py install

and get error:

```
C:\Users\Marko Z\Desktop\cython-master\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c: In function '__Pyx_ImportType':
C:\Users\Marko Z\Desktop\cython-master\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c:11981:13: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
         "%s.%s size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected %zd, got %zd",
         ^
C:\Users\Marko Z\Desktop\cython-master\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c:11981:13: 
warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
C:\Users\Marko Z\Desktop\cython-master\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c:11981:13: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
writing c:\users\marko z\desktop\cython-master\cython\plex\Scanners.cp37-win32.def
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -shared -s "c:\users\marko z\desktop\cython-master\cython\plex\scanners.o" "c:\users\marko z\desktop\cython-master\cython\plex\Scanners.cp37-win32.def" "-LC:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs" "-LC:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\PCbuild\win32" -lpython37 -o build\lib.win32-3.7\Cython\Plex\Scanners.cp37-win32.pyd
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs/libpython37.a when searching for -lpython37
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs/python37.lib when searching for -lpython37
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs\libpython37.a when searching for -lpython37
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs/libpython37.a when searching for -lpython37
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs/python37.lib when searching for -lpython37
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\Marko Z\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs\python37.lib when searching for -lpython37
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython37
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

I try to follow the instruction by:

- [Indrajit Kanjilal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135280/valueerror-unknown-ms-compiler-version-1900)

and also

- [sjp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488163/python-3-4-compile-cython-module-for-64-bit-windows)

(I try with patch to create object `Mingw64CCompiler` and then remove all instances of `-mno-cygwin`, but I get the same error...)