# ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900

Tags: python, visual-studio, cygwin, mingw, distutils

I am trying to run some code with Python 3.5 on Windows 10 with the use of cygwin (mingw). To be precise I am using the PyDSTool module, where I call the dopri integrator. The problem is, I am having trouble with `distutils` not recognizing Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. Is there a way to avoid this (without going back to older versions of Python, Windows, Visual Studio). The full Error can be seen bellow.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-bfeb915bfd7b> in <module>()
     60 print("\n")
     61 
---> 62 testODE = Dopri_ODEsystem(DSargs)
     63 
     64 print('Integrating...')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\Generator\Dopri_ODEsystem.py in __init__(self, kw)
    371             print("stages using the makeLibSource and compileLib methods.")
    372         else:
--> 373             self.makeLib()
    374 
    375     @property

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\Generator\mixins.py in makeLib(self, libsources, libdirs, include)
     98             self.forceLibRefresh()
     99         self.makeLibSource(include)
--> 100         self.compileLib(libsources, libdirs)
    101 
    102     @property

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\Generator\mixins.py in compileLib(self, libsources, libdirs)
     78           precompiled libraries."""
     79 
---> 80         self._builder.build(libsources, libdirs, self._compiler)
     81 
     82     def forceLibRefresh(self):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyDSTool\Generator\mixins.py in build(self, libsources, libdirs, compiler)
    187                   script_args=script_args,
    188                   ext_modules=[extmod],
--> 189                   py_modules=[self.modname])
    190 
    191     def save_vfield(self, code, fname=None):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py in setup(**attr)
    167     new_attr['distclass'] = NumpyDistribution
    168 
--> 169     return old_setup(**new_attr)
    170 
    171 def _check_append_library(libraries, item):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py in setup(**attrs)
    146     if ok:
    147         try:
--> 148             dist.run_commands()
    149         except KeyboardInterrupt:
    150             raise SystemExit("interrupted")

C:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py in run_commands(self)
    953         """
    954         for cmd in self.commands:
--> 955             self.run_command(cmd)
    956 
    957     # -- Methods that operate on its Commands --------------------------

C:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py in run_command(self, command)
    972         cmd_obj = self.get_command_obj(command)
    973         cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
--> 974         cmd_obj.run()
    975         self.have_run[command] = 1
    976 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py in run(self)
    115                                      verbose=self.verbose,
    116                                      dry_run=self.dry_run,
--> 117                                      force=self.force)
    118         self.compiler.customize(self.distribution)
    119         self.compiler.customize_cmd(self)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py in new_compiler(plat, compiler, verbose, dry_run, force)
    594         raise DistutilsModuleError(("can't compile C/C++ code: unable to find class '%s' " +
    595                "in module '%s'") % (class_name, module_name))
--> 596     compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
    597     log.debug('new_compiler returns %s' % (klass))
    598     return compiler

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py in __init__(self, verbose, dry_run, force)
     56 
     57         distutils.cygwinccompiler.CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose,
---> 58                                                             dry_run, force)
     59 
     60         # we need to support 3.2 which doesn't match the standard

C:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py in __init__(self, verbose, dry_run, force)
    159             # Include the appropriate MSVC runtime library if Python was built
    160             # with MSVC 7.0 or later.
--> 161             self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()
    162 
    163     def _compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py in get_msvcr()
     88         #     return ['vcruntime140']
     89         else:
---> 90             raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
     91 
     92 

ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900
```

Answer (score 20):

I made the following changes and it worked for me with the following configurations.

- OS : Win 7 Prof. SP1 64 bit
- CPython 3.6 , 64 Bit
- Mingw 64 (x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0)
- [Cython 0.25.2](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

I did the following

1. Add mingw in the PATH variable (`C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin` for me)
2. Test by opening command line and command `gcc` works ( I have no other compilers)
3. Create `distutils.cfg` in `C:\Python36\Lib\distutils`
4. Add lines in that file:

   ```
   [build]
   compiler = mingw32
   ```
5. Manually applying [this patch](https://bugs.python.org/file40608/patch.diff)
6. Manually downloading the file `vcruntime140.dll` and putting it in `C:\Python36\libs`

Comment: Evrything worked fine this way till I found that MingW w64 defines "hypot = hypot" and in pyconfig.h , it is defined as "hypot = _hypot". Hence generating compiler errors in some cases. The fix is: 1) Either temporarily edit pyconfig.h with making the line "#define hypot _hypot" to "#define hypot hypot", and then run the cython process. 2) In setup.py, add a new param to "ext = Extension("...",..,..,extra_compile_args=['...', '-D_hypot=hypot', '..'])" ... This problem specifically happens when there is a C++ compile with the  Cython code, it appears.

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Windows 10 with Anaconda 3

Comment: If you cant make it work give compiler=mingw32.exe a try also - it worked for me, while compiler=mingw32 didn't.

Comment: PS: If you are using anaconda, just copy `vcruntime140.dll` from `D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\vcruntime140.dll` to `somewhere\Python3.6\libs`

Comment: Hi, I try the same, but when I do in pyrfc: python setup.py install I get this error: error Microsoft Visual C 14.0 is required

Answer (score 10):

Distutils and Numpy/Distutils currently do not have support for Visual Studio 2015, Visual C++ 14.  Following tips drawn from the Python bug [report](https://bugs.python.org/issue25251), I was able to patch the necessary files and successfully build extension using a new install of Python 3.5 from Anaconda and Mingw64 with GCC 5.2.0 running within MSYS2 on Windows 7.  I do not have Visual Studio installed.  The solution was to patch one distutils file and two numpy/distutils files (if this applies).  These patches have been submitted for inclusion in future revisions.

You can apply the patches yourself for a quick fix:

- distutils [patch](https://bugs.python.org/file40608/patch.diff)
- numpy/distutils [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/numpy/numpy/pull/6875.diff)

**UPDATE**

Please note that while the patches above worked for me it was not accepted for inclusion in upstream.  The changes that came with VS 2015 are more complex than I appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone still has this problem,i just ran into it while installing yowsup and python-axolotl, this is what i did to solve it:

1- Apply the patch from Tharen into the python cygwinccompiler.py file (located in your python installation folder) https://bugs.python.org/file40608/patch.diff

2-With mingw, install pexports, open a terminal in administrator mode and type:

```
mingw-get install pexports
```

2-Go to the python install folder, in my case it was C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32

still in the same terminal we used to install pexports, after navigating to the python install folder run the following:

```
pexports vcruntime140.dll >libs\vcruntime140.def
dlltool -dllname vcruntime140.dll --def libs\vcruntime140.def --output-lib libs\libvcruntime140.a
```

Then go back to the folder where you were installing the library, or whatever you were doing before, it should work now.

btw, dont forget to add

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

in the distutils file.

Source: this own post and https://bugs.python.org/issue25251

Comment: `pexports` is `gendef` in mingw-w64-i686-tools or mingw-w64-x86_64-tools  under msys2 .

Answer (score 6):

I was running on the same problem and figured out that the issue was with the mingw compiler. I tried the patches suggested by @tharen but it didn't work for me.

It seems that cygwin's favourite compiler for windows is the visual c++ so I downloaded just the visual c++ build tools from http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
and then it worked fine.

Note that you will need to uninstall mingw and all references to it that you included in your project. In particular I had to delete a distutils.cfg file that I had created which had the following code pointing to mingw

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

Answer (score 4):

Details in [link](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2751) helped me resolve this like a charm.

Just commented `get_msvcr()` in cygwinccompiler.py.

(remember to comment the `else` also)

Comment: where is cygwinccompiler.py?

Answer (score 1):

I just made he following changes and it worked like a charm!

Edit file distutils.cfg present in locations:

1. C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\distutils\
2. C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs\libpython-2.0-py36_0\Lib\distutils

Modify content of distutils.cfg to :

```
[build]
compiler=g++

[build_ext]           
compiler=g++
```

P.S. Probably changing only in 2nd location should also do.

P.P.S Make sure gcc is installed and is in PATH. For me , TDM-GCC-64 was installed