# Python C++ Build yields Value Error: "Symbol table not found"

Tags: python, c++, numpy, mingw, distutils

I am trying to build the [paratext](https://github.com/wiseio/paratext) Python module (need to do it from source) on windows, and am experiencing compiler issues. Specifically, using the mingw compiler results in two issues:

1) objdump.exe:

> C:\Users\aagnone3\Anaconda3\python35.dll: File format not recognized

2) Second:

> ValueError: Symbole table not found (thrown in
>   numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py)

Any pointers? The full output is below

Command: `python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32 > results.txt`

> /cygdrive/c/Users/aagnone3-gtri/Anaconda3/Library/bin/swig
>   0.1.1rc1 running swig:  ['swig', '-c++', '-python', '-py3', '-I../src/', '-outdir', './', '../src/paratext_internal.i'] running
>   build running config_cc unifing config_cc, config, build_clib,
>   build_ext, build commands --compiler options running config_fc unifing
>   config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler
>   options running build_src build_src building py_modules sources
>   building extension "_paratext_internal" sources build_src: building
>   npy-pkg config files running build_py copying paratext_internal.py ->
>   build\lib.win-amd64-3.5 copying paratext__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\paratext running build_ext Looking for
>   python35.dll Building import library (arch=AMD64):
>   "C:\Users\aagnone3-gtri\Anaconda3\libs\libpython35.a" (from
>   C:\Users\aagnone3-gtri\Anaconda3\python35.dll)

Comment: Unless stated, common python distributions are built with vcc/VisualStudio and it is recommended you use that toolchain to build extensions. Using other (s.a. mingw) is not recommended or supported.

Comment: this build process uses compiler flags that are not recognized by vc compilers

Comment: From the looks of it, the developers are not supporting non *nix environments implicitly. You should file a ticket for vc support and/or work it out yourself and make a pull request. My guess is that the non-vc-compatible flags is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises from the use of mingw as a compiler in Windows. It is known to perform poorly. See answers to the following question for solutions
[ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135280/valueerror-unknown-ms-compiler-version-1900)