# Raw socket packet sniffer in Python 3.6 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to sniff packets but i am getting strange output and i don't understand the reason..
 So that's my code **please** help me
(I'm using Python 3.6 on Windows 8.1)

### Code:

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii
import textwrap

def main():
    # Get host
    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print('IP: {}'.format(host))

    # Create a raw socket and bind it
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    conn.bind((host, 0))

    # Include IP headers
    conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    # Enable promiscuous mode
    conn.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

    while True:
        # Recive data
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65536)

        # Unpack data
        dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(raw_data)

        print('\nEthernet Frame:')
        print("Destination MAC: {}".format(dest_mac))
        print("Source MAC: {}".format(src_mac))
        print("Protocol: {}".format(eth_proto))

# Unpack ethernet frame
def ethernet_frame(data):
    dest_mac, src_mac, proto = struct.unpack('!6s6s2s', data[:14])
    return get_mac_addr(dest_mac), get_mac_addr(src_mac), get_protocol(proto), data[14:]

# Return formatted MAC address AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
def get_mac_addr(bytes_addr):
    bytes_str = map('{:02x}'.format, bytes_addr)
    mac_address = ':'.join(bytes_str).upper()
    return mac_address

# Return formatted protocol ABCD
def get_protocol(bytes_proto):
    bytes_str = map('{:02x}'.format, bytes_proto)
    protocol = ''.join(bytes_str).upper()
    return protocol

main()
```

### From this code i get this output:

IP: 192.168.1.12

Ethernet Frame:
Destination MAC: **45:00:00:43:00:00**
Source MAC: **40:00:2C:11:48:D3**
Protocol: **4266**

Ethernet Frame:
Destination MAC: **45:00:00:42:11:E7**
Source MAC: **00:00:80:11:00:00**
Protocol: **C0A8**

Ethernet Frame:
Destination MAC: **45:00:00:33:04:D6**
Source MAC: **00:00:80:11:00:00**
Protocol: **C0A8**

.
.
.

According to [EtherType list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType) this protocols don't exist and analysing my traffic with Wireshark i am sure that this MACs don't exist in my LAN

So I'm definitely doing something wrong but I do not understand what
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is that all your Destination Mac addresses start with `0x45`.  That's  the first byte of the [IP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure). So your code is getting all the IP packets, but not the MAC header for those frames.

Comment: But how can i get MAC header? (i am new with Python)

Comment: Instead of opening an AF_INET socket, open an AF_PACKET socket. http://opensourceforu.com/2015/03/a-guide-to-using-raw-sockets/

Answer (score 5):

Ok thanks to **selbi** i understand the problem, thank you very much
 
But to catch Ethernet header with Python in windows you have to use:

## 1. PyPCap

- To [install pypcap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515474/installing-pypcap-on-windows-10-python-2-7-64-bit)

## 2. Dpkt

- To install dpkt just open cmd as admin and type:

  py -2 -m pip install dpkt

Here references of [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)

## 3. Python 2.7

But you need to install Python 3.4> to get pip

## And finally that's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import getopt, sys
import dpkt, pcap
import socket
import struct
import binascii
import textwrap

def main():
    # Get host
    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print('IP: {}'.format(host))

    name = None            
    pc = pcap.pcap(name)
    decode = { pcap.DLT_LOOP:dpkt.loopback.Loopback,
               pcap.DLT_NULL:dpkt.loopback.Loopback,
               pcap.DLT_EN10MB:dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet }[pc.datalink()]
    try:
        print 'listening on %s: %s' % (pc.name, pc.filter)
        for ts, pkt in pc:
            pkt = str(decode(pkt))
            dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(pkt)

            print '\nEthernet Frame:'
            print "Destination MAC: {}".format(dest_mac)
            print "Source: {}".format(src_mac)
            print "Protocol: {}".format(eth_proto)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        nrecv, ndrop, nifdrop = pc.stats()
        print '\n%d packets received by filter' % nrecv
        print '%d packets dropped by kernel' % ndrop

# Unpack ethernet frame
def ethernet_frame(data):
    dest_mac, src_mac, proto = struct.unpack('!6s6s2s', data[:14])
    return binascii.hexlify(dest_mac), binascii.hexlify(src_mac), binascii.hexlify(proto), data[14:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Output:

Ethernet Frame:
Destination MAC: **5404a6f2740c <- My NIC MAC**
Source: **6459f81dc690**
Protocol: **0800 <- Right protocol**

Ethernet Frame:
Destination MAC: **6459f81dc690**
Source: **5404a6f2740c**
Protocol: **0800**

Ethernet Frame:
Destination MAC: **5404a6f2740c**
Source: **6459f81dc690**
Protocol: **0800**

I hope you enjoy thanks again **selbie**

(Sorry i can't put more links cause of my reputation)

Comment: I have tried the above same packet sniffer code. it was not working on my windows 10.

Comment: @krish the question is old.. I will try to fix it as soon as possible. Which errors do you get?

Comment: The total Ethernet frame is mismatched. it has not given proper source mac and des mac