# Can't install pcap in pycharm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I try install pcap package in pycharam tools but did not install and **show blow error :**

> Collecting pcap Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement pcap (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for
>   pcap

how can i  fix installing package?

Comment: which OS are you using? Have you installed the pcab library?

Comment: Could you please share your requirements.txt?

Comment: I'm using windows.of course.in pycharm i select pcap libraray but tools show the error?(did you mean pcap or pcab).

Comment: I want to capture network send and receive package .

Comment: Check that out, you're not the only one: https://github.com/dugsong/pypcap/issues/27
A workaround is proposed there.
Also check that out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515474/installing-pypcap-on-windows-10-python-2-7-64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, go to the location where you had installed your setup and use this command to install the missing package:

`pip install pcap`