# how to remedy mno cygwin error?

Tags: gcc, windows-8, cygwin, gnu-make

I'm working on compiling a library in windows with GCC and Make.
When I run `make`, I get the following error:

`unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'`

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o#6035864) on SO, but it doesn't necessarily seem like the same issue, and I don't understand how to downgrade my system to a version of GCC (or Make) that supports the flag I need to use in order to compile.

Could someone please try to point me in the right direction, or if you've run into this problem offer a solution?

I'm running Windows 8.1 pro, GCC 5.4.0, make 4.2.1.
I can post more info if it is necessary to help me.

Comment: The post you link to suggests removing the flag, did you try that?

Comment: I didn't try that, thanks.  I'll post back if that fixes my issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The current cygwin gcc compiles only for cygwin itself.

`-mno-cygwin` is an obsolete flag from gcc 3.x time that allowed the cygwin compiler to compile mingw (not cygwin) programs.

The switch was removed long time ago and true cross compilers

mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core
 mingw64-i686-gcc-core
 cygwin-mingw

were made available

Latest update:
https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-11/msg00020.html

Comment: Thanks.  The compiler I was using was `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`

Comment: I'm having an issue calling up the newer core compiler by name with a Makefile.  Can you link me to an intro on how to do this in a Makefile?

Comment: Should be enough to define `CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`

Comment: To be clear: Simply dropping that command line option should be fine in an all cygwin environment?  It's only a problem if you're compiling **in cygwin, for mingw**?

Comment: Then, what is the equivalent to `-mno-cygwin` now? I have no clue what this switch does, but it must be in my code. My compiler is `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`.

Comment: `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` already behave as the old `-mno-cygwin` switch.