# Compiling required external modules with cython

Tags: python, cython, psycopg2

I'm building a standalone executable using Cython on Linux.

I have the following code:

```
import psycopg2 as pg

conn = pg.connect('dbname=**** user=**** password=****')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT version()')
print(cur.fetchone())
```

The problem is when the machine does not have the Python package psycopg2 installed, throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 2, in init test (test.c:872)
    import psycopg2 as pg
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Im building using the `--embed` cython flag.

How can I make Cython to compile that particular package too?

Comment: Cython is mainly used to build extensions, not standalone executables. To create standalone executables you can use pyinstaller. If you elaborate more about your building setup, I could try to help. I dont say that cython with the --embed option cannot do it, but pyinstaller helps a lot collecting all the dependencies into the executable.

Comment: Can Cython be used to compile external Python modules? Let's say I want to create a function that queries a PostgreSQL database, I use the psycopg2 module, there is a way to automatically build that module too? @drodri

Comment: You can find [this experimental script](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Tools/cystdlib.py) which compile the standard library. There's a good chance that you can compile `psycopg2` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience, it is not that straightforward to create a standalone executable from multiples python files (yours or from dependencies like psycopg2).
I would say there are a couple of approaches here I would try:

The first one would be cython_freeze https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Demos/freeze I do not use it myself, so I cannot tell much.

The second one is to use pyinstaller to create such executable. It takes as input the .py or .pyc files and embed them into one executable, together with the python interpreter and required dependencies, so you don't have to install anything on the target machine. Note, however, that your code will run as interpreted python and can be easily decompiled and inspected.

If you really need to compile (cythonize) your code, then you can first cythonize() and the build with setup() your extensions, then run pyinstaller as above (taking care that it doesnt find the .py or .pyc files, just the .pyd or .so extensions) to generate the standalone executable. In both cases, pyinstaller will collect all your dependencies and embed them in the executable (even if it fails, you can tell pyinstaller to embed them with hidden_imports).

There are surely other approaches, like py2exe, but when I researched and played with several technologies some months ago, pyinstaller was the best option for me. I do the process in win, linux and mac without many changes.

**EDIT:** I didn't realize that the example is python 3. Pyinstaller only works for 2.x now.

Comment: PyInstaller is great, the only issue I have with it is that doesn't support Python 3 yet.

Comment: I see, I didnt realize your code is Python 3, sorry

Comment: That happens when 90% of python use is in 2.X ;) http://alexgaynor.net/2014/jan/03/pypi-download-statistics/

Comment: I understand, also, the only Python 3 line is the one with the print, and that's also valid in Python 2, so, my bad... :)

Answer (score 5):

--embed means the Python interpreter is embedded in your executable. It does not mean independence from Python. It does not do what you think. It sounds more like you need a tool like py2exe, py2app or pyfreeze.

Answer (score 4):

[Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html) is the tool that you need.

> You feed it your Python app, it does a lot of clever things, and spits out an executable or extension module.
>
> Right now Nuitka is a good replacement for the Python interpreter and compiles every construct that CPython 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3 and 3.4 offer. It translates the Python into a C++ program that then uses "libpython" to execute in the same way as CPython does, in a very compatible way.
>
> It is somewhat faster than CPython already, but currently it doesn't make all the optimizations possible, but a 258% factor on pystone is a good start (number is from version 0.3.11).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but I stumbled across this question when I had a similar problem. My solution is to add the missing modules to the PyInstaller as `--hidden-imports`.

So

```
python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile <your.py> --hidden-import=<missed module>
```

This will not compile the module with cython. However, this is also not a requirement from your question.