# Creating an executable from Cython Code

Tags: python, compilation, executable, cython

I am trying to create an executable in cython, following the directions here: 
[Making an executable in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython).
However, I keep getting the error "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16' collect2.exe and I am curious to know what the cause of this is.

Edited:

I am currently doing the following things with the following Cython file:

```
cpdef primes(int kmax):
cdef int n, k, i
cdef int p[1000]
result = []
if kmax > 1000:
    kmax = 1000
k = 0
n = 2
while k < kmax:
    i = 0
    while i < k and n % p[i] != 0:
        i = i + 1
    if i == k:
        p[k] = n
        k = k + 1
        result.append(n)
    n = n + 1
return result
```

1. Running through the command line the commands:

cython primes.pyx --embed

gcc -DMS_WIN64 -mthreads -mconsole -Wall -O -IC:\Python34\include -LC:\Python34\libs setup.c -lpython34 -o example.exe

And the error that I get is:

"c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'"

Thank you kindly!

Comment: See if this applies, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16 and/or try adding for example `-mconsole` compile flag.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work either :(

Comment: I think you should edit your question, and put in more detail what you are trying to do, like the commands used to compile and link. Also the cython command used.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala. Thank you. I just edited it.

Comment: Do you have a method named main() in your *.pyx* file?

Comment: No. I don't. I inserted one, but the same message appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command compiled your cython program

```
gcc -municode -DMS_WIN64 -O -Wall -I /c/devel/Python34/include -L /c/devel/Python34/libs/ primes.c -lpython34 -o example.exe
```

This was done in a windows 7 64bit msys2 environment using gcc 4.9.1 and 5.3.0 64bit versions (win32 threads, SEH exception handling) and 64bit python 3.4.

My original thought was that there would be a problem because of missing *main()* but *cython* silently adds one.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. What operating system are you using, perchance? Because it tells me that the line option "-municode" does not exist

Comment: @smallfacebigmouth I did not notice that you had rather old compiler i.e. 4.8.1. I think it is a poor match when working with Python 3.4 since it does not have `-municode` like newer version. *python --embed* produces code that needs unicode support from compiler.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well. I worked around that by ignoring the -municode and when the .c file is generated from Cython, to replace the "wmain" with "main". That did the trick

Comment: I get undefined reference to `wWinMain'