# Create Executable from a Python module with Pyinstaller or Cython

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I want to convert to an executable [this](https://github.com/libindic/indic-trans) python 2.7 project that has a module structure:

```
(.venv) ip-192-168-22-127:indictrans loretoparisi$ tree -L 1
.
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── __init__.spec
├── _decode
├── _utils
├── base.py
├── build
├── mappings
├── models
├── script_transliterate.py
├── tests
├── transliterator.py
└── trunk
```

I'm using `pyinstaller` for this at first stage I'm just doing:

```
pyinstall --onefile __init__.py
```

and I get a executable built:

```
192 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
192 INFO: Python: 2.7.10
201 INFO: Platform: Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
202 INFO: wrote /Users/loretoparisi/Documents/Projects/AI/indic-trans/indictrans/__init__.spec
208 INFO: UPX is not available.
209 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/loretoparisi/Documents/Projects/AI/indic-trans',
 '/Users/loretoparisi/Documents/Projects/AI/indic-trans/indictrans']
210 INFO: checking Analysis
218 INFO: checking PYZ
223 INFO: checking PKG
224 INFO: Bootloader /Users/loretoparisi/Documents/Projects/AI/indic-trans/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/run
224 INFO: checking EXE
225 INFO: Rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because __init__ missing
225 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
225 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /Users/loretoparisi/Documents/Projects/AI/indic-trans/indictrans/dist/__init__
230 INFO: Fixing EXE for code signing /Users/loretoparisi/Documents/Projects/AI/indic-trans/indictrans/dist/__init__
234 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
```

But when I run it I get an import error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "indictrans/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
[30629] Failed to execute script __init__
```

This library is built using **Cython** via cythonize setup, so another option would be to build a executable embedded module using the `--embed` Cython option.

My `setup.py` is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy


os.environ['PBR_VERSION'] = '1.2.3'
os.environ['SKIP_WRITE_GIT_CHANGELOG'] = '1'
os.environ['SKIP_GENERATE_AUTHORS'] = '1'


extensions = [
    Extension(
        "indictrans._decode.beamsearch",
        [
            "indictrans/_decode/beamsearch.pyx"
        ],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
    ),
    Extension(
        "indictrans._decode.viterbi",
        [
            "indictrans/_decode/viterbi.pyx"
        ],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
    ),
    Extension(
        "indictrans._utils.ctranxn",
        [
            "indictrans/_utils/ctranxn.pyx"
        ],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
    ),
    Extension(
        "indictrans._utils.sparseadd",
        [
            "indictrans/_utils/sparseadd.pyx"
        ],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
    )

]

setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr'],
    pbr=True,
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)
```

While it's easy to compile a singe python file with the `--embed option`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython?lq=1) for more about this, I do not know how to use the `--embed` option in the `setup.py` in order to get rid of all the dependencies in the project.

Comment: which is the main file you start with python? is it `transliterator.py`

Comment: @Stack I thinks this is part of the problem, since the main is within the `__init__.py` file that handles the arguments and pass it to the `Transliterator` class imported from ther `transliterator.py`.

Comment: try `pyinstaller --onefile transliterator.py` or move the main to another new file and try with that

Comment: @Stack thanks, I would prefer to not change the module structure, since this will be an automatic build system from the sources. By the way I have added more info about `setup.py` and `Cython`, if you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*I'm going to refer to the root package directory with the `setup.py` file as the **package** directory, which is `indic-trans` in your case. I'm referring to the first level source directory as the **module** directory, which is `indic-trans/indictrans` in your case.*

---

If I understand your setup correctly, you have an issue because of trying to create an `.exe` on a script within the **module** directory rather than the **package** directory.  This makes the current directory the internal module directory, and relative references will not work.

The way I resolved this in a similar situation was to create a `run.py` script in the main **package** directory (same folder as `setup.py`) which imports the package and then runs whatever script you want to run inside the **module** directory.

You didn't post the `__init__.py` file (by the way, it is generally frowned upon to have any real code in `__init.py__`...), so I'll assume for the below that you want to run the `main()` function in the `base.py` script.  In that case, make `run.py` something like:

```py
# This will import everything from the module __init__.py based on it's "all" setup
# You likely want to limit it to just what is needed or just the script you are targeting
# Or you can use the "import indictrans" format and let __init__.py handle it
from indictrans import * 

def main():
    indictrans.base.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now you can run just `run.py` from the command line or use it as a debug target to run your package.

Note that with PyInstaller you can target `run.py` (or `run.spec`) and change the name to something else with the `--name` argument.

```py
pyinstaller --onefile --name indictrans run.spec
```

which will create `indictrans.exe` in the `dist` directory.

---

#### Running your package as a module

Note that in the **module** directory, you can also create a `__main__.py` file that is basically as copy of `run.py` and does the same thing, but will be run as a module by the Python executable if it is installed locally.

i.e. `python -m indictrans` will run your package using `__main__.py` as the entrypoint.