# undefined reference to `main' cannot find entry symbol _start

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython, program-entry-point

I am trying to compile a python program to c file.First, After going through and eliminating tens of errors with dozens of linking flags, finally left with a single error. When I type:

```
$ gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.6m -o example example_cy.c -lpython3.6m     -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

the error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':                                                
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'                                                                                                          
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I add **-nostartfiles**:

```
gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.6m -o example example_cy.c
-lpython3.6m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl -nostartfiles
```

The error becomes:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to  
00000000000022f0
```

I got the image that the problem is roughly do have neither main nor _start function in my .c file.

Comment: That's correct. Better go with a `main()` function and drop the `-nostartfiles` thingie. What's your exact question or problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an executable in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython)

Comment: cython generates main-method, if you cythonize with --embed. See the duplicate target for more info.