# How to compile python code using cython --embed?

Tags: python

These are incomplete examples and are not helpful.

What is a minimal complete example. I mean something that produces a binary from a python script.

https://ron.sh/compiling-python-code-with-cython/

[Making an executable in Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extremely simple example. I am peforming this from a Debian Sid workstation, using python3 and cython3..

Make sure you have **python-dev** or **python3-dev** packages installed beforehand.

**1)** Create a very simple Python program called **hello.py**

> $ cat hello.py
>
> print("Hello World!")

**2)** Use Cython to compile your python program into C...

```
cython3 --embed -o hello.c hello.py
```

**3)** Use GCC to compile hello.c into an executable file called **hello**...

```
gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.3m -o hello hello.c -lpython3.3m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

**4)** You end up with a file called **hello** ...

Comment: Awesome. This works ... do you happen to know what needs to be included when important other libraries like pandas or anything else? I feel like I did this many years ago ... have another question on that detail now.