How to compile a python program without using pyinstaller or py2exe?
I would like to know if there is any way to compile a python program into an .exe file and speed it up.
Or maybe try to create my own C / C++ standalone exe that will run an embedded python interpreter with the script. And i would like to have some speed increase in the execution of a python script.
I tried this, but this cannot be standalone because it needs some dlls to come with it:
#include <python.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello World!')");
    Py_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}

So these are my questions:

How to compile a python program without using pyinstaller or py2exe?
How to create my own standalone program that will run the python script. (like pyinstaller does)


Take a look at Cython: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507592/making-an-executable-in-cython

pyinstaller doesn't compile it - it creates self-extracting .zip file with extension .exe
